# Linking Javascript to HTML in a Python Webserver

Tags: javascript, python, html

Using Python 3 with Socket.

I'm having trouble linking a javascript file to an HTML file. I have the following 3 files in particular in the same directory:

**webserver.py**

```
import socket

def getTextFromFile(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as myFile:
        return myFile.read()

host, port = '192.168.0.7', 11010

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(1)

print('Now serving: ' + host + ' at: ' + str(port))

while True:
    try:
        c, addr = s.accept()
        print('Received connection form: ' + str(addr))
        request = c.recv(1024)
        response = '\HTTP/1.1 200 OK' + getTextFromFile("index.html")
        c.sendall(response.encode())
        c.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<script src="indexjs.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Hello there.</h1>
<p>This is a webserver test.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click me!</button>
<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

**indexjs.js**

```
function myFunction(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello";
}
```

The web server code itself works fine, the router is port-forwarded, can be accessed from an entirely different network, yada-yada; but when the website is visited, the javascript doesn't seem to execute. If I place the same javascript code inside the script tags of index.html and omit indexjs.js then it does work as intended. How do I make it to where indexjs.js can be properly linked with index.html without putting the javascript code in script tags?

I also tried another similar approach by trying to put an image in index.html (png file, same directory as index.html of course) with the img tags, but it did not display either, so it seems like my code is having issues linking any files to index.html whatsoever.

**The steps I'm taking:**

Run webserver.py

Open browser (in my case it happens to be Chrome)

Type in my public ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:11010 in the address bar, hit enter

The web page shows, but pictures don't show (or any other asset that's linked) and javascript functions aren't executed when, for example, buttons are pressed.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would have a public folder for your static assets. And you would put your static css and js files into it.

Comment: They are all in the same directory though. To my knowledge this is normally allowed and should work, but for some reason it isn't working.